How to remove minify from flutter web URL (https://energymaxapp.com/webapp/minified:lM)
So, I have published an webapp with flutter and it is behaving strange when I am releasing it. In local host it is working completely fine with proper URL structure.
It is showing this kind of URL - https://energymaxapp.com/webapp/minified:lM (with minified and than random alphabets)
I have already used url_strategy package to remove the hash and it worked but this is still happening and when I am reloading the page it is showing 404 as https://energymaxapp.com/webapp is exist but https://energymaxapp.com/webapp/minified:lM is not.

How are you handling the URL / routes in your code?

I have just added setPathUrlStrategy(); this function in my main() as per the package instruction.

@RodrigoMolero Other than that I am pushing users to another page using Get.to(PageName());
